# Socket.io not sharing sessions with express

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, cookies, socket.io

I can't figure why this is happening exactly since it was working perfectly before.

I'm using the following libraries:

```
"express-socket.io-session": "^1.3.2"
"socket.io": "^2.0.3"
"express": "^4.15.4"
"express-session": "^1.15.5"
```

1 - I login the user via a http request and send the cookie back to the frontend. **All operations on http work perfectly with the cookie in frontend backend exchanges**.

2 - After the user is logged in I tell the frontend "ok, user is logged in, now connect to the sockets":

```
io ( this.url );
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
var io_session = require("express-socket.io-session");
var e_session = require("express-session");

var sessionFileStore = require('session-file-store')(e_session);

var ee_session = e_session({
    store: new sessionFileStore({ path: './user_sessions' }),
    secret: "something-random",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});

var enableCORS = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, *');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',true);

        // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    };
};

app.use(function(req, res, next) {      
  ///
   next();
});

//app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(enableCORS);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(ee_session);

preparedApp = require("http").Server(app);

var io = require("socket.io")(preparedApp);

io.use(io_session(e_session,{
    autoSave: true
}));

preparedApp.listen(8080, function(){});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    var socket_session = socket.handshake.session,
        socket_session_id = socket.handshake.sessionID;

    console.log("SOCKET_SESSION:",socket_session);
    console.log("SOCKET_SESSION_ID:",socket_session_id);

    (...)
```

3 - `socket_session` is 'empty' but everything in the regular http cookies works. The session is maintained there.

One thing I noticed is that `socket_session_id` points to a session file **that does not exist** inside the folder user_sessions. The only ones that exist are created in the http login. So, basically:

> => User logins: efihaeif939311kf3f3 session id file is created.
>
> => Socket connects: fiaejgieofaekofek is the session id in the same login flow **but file does not exist** in user_sessions (note that the session id is not the same)

Any idea on why this is happening? I have absolutely no idea.

Thanks

Comment: `var e_session = e_session({ ... })` is bad, I'd rename the var to `session` so it's clear and you don't overwrite the import ref (it may actually be the source of your problem).

Comment: @James Already did but the problem persists.

Comment: @James no other idea? Still stuck :(

Comment: I mean there are obvious issues that may be the problem I don't want to keep asking, please put a small, but complete, example of the code that isn't working so I can properly diagnose.

Comment: The code that "is not working" is exactly above... The console logs are not the same, the session id is not the same despite the fact that the user logs in the http correctly, is returned to the frontend and then the frontend sends a socket request...

Comment: it's not a complete example though i.e. I couldn't drop that into a debugger and reproduce the issue could I? I'd need to make assumptions about your express config etc. - see [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I prefer not to debug by proxy....

Comment: @James as you can imagine it's pretty hard or "impossible" to reproduce an error dependent on both frontend and backend handshake whastmore one that involves third party libraries xD anything and everything I could ever do related to the error is shown above...

Comment: it was really more just to get an idea of your backend code to see exactly how it's glued together. So I'm to assume you have your express session being configured somewhere, is this before or after your socket IO session? If it's after, try configuring express first then socket.io (this is why I wanted to see the code in a short, but complete example, this is now debugging by proxy :/).

Comment: @James The code is in the order shown in the question. I still can't figure why this is happening

Comment: at what point do you configure your express session?

Comment: @James I've included more code related to the situation, please do check it out. Thank you very much for your help James, I certainly need it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156821/discussion-between-james-and-fane).

Comment: Try binding to socket events before having the server listen for connections

Comment: Any feedback on comments I posted on chat?

Comment: Hello @TarunLalwani, unfortunately the problem persists...

Answer (score 0):

try sharing the session by stringifying the session json and retrieving and parsing back to session object in the client side.

This might work.

Comment: It will most probably work yes but it will also render the app vulnerable to identity attacks, most likely...